# Drag and Drop in JList is not working

Tags: java, swing, jlist, drag-and-drop

So I have written a TransferHandler for my application (along the example from Oracle site) but when I am trying to move the data it is not moving. All it is doing is copying the data at index ( n-1 i.e if I am moving and item to n location) to index n. Could you please check what is wrong, though I have tried many options but none of them is working for me.

```
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;

    public class ListTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
        private int[] indices = null;
        private int addIndex = -1; //Location where items were added
        private int addCount = 0;  //Number of items added.

        public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
            // Check for String flavor
            if (!info.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
            return new StringSelection(exportString(c));
        }

        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            return TransferHandler.MOVE;
        }

        public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
            if (!info.isDrop()) {
                return false;
            }

            JList list = (JList)info.getComponent();
            DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
            JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation)info.getDropLocation();
            int index = dl.getIndex();
            boolean insert = dl.isInsert();

            // Get the string that is being dropped.
            Transferable t = info.getTransferable();
            String data;
            try {
                data = (String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { return false; }

            // Perform the actual import.  
            if (insert) {
                listModel.add(index, data);
            } else {
                listModel.set(index, data);
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable data, int action) {
            cleanup(c, action == TransferHandler.MOVE);
        }

        //Bundle up the selected items in the list
        //as a single string, for export.
        protected String exportString(JComponent c) {
            JList list = (JList)c;
            indices = list.getSelectedIndices();
            Object[] values = list.getSelectedValues();

            StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                Object val = values[i];
                buff.append(val == null ? "" : val.toString());
                if (i != values.length - 1) {
                    buff.append("\n");
                }
            }

            return buff.toString();
        }

        //Take the incoming string and wherever there is a
        //newline, break it into a separate item in the list.
        protected void importString(JComponent c, String str) {
            JList target = (JList)c;
            DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel)target.getModel();
            int index = target.getSelectedIndex();

            //Prevent the user from dropping data back on itself.
            //For example, if the user is moving items #4,#5,#6 and #7 and
            //attempts to insert the items after item #5, this would
            //be problematic when removing the original items.
            //So this is not allowed.
            if (indices != null && index >= indices[0] - 1 &&
                  index <= indices[indices.length - 1]) {
                indices = null;
                return;
            }

            int max = listModel.getSize();
            if (index < 0) {
                index = max;
            } else {
                index++;
                if (index > max) {
                    index = max;
                }
            }
            addIndex = index;
            String[] values = str.split("\n");
            addCount = values.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                listModel.add(index++, values[i]);
            }
        }

        //If the remove argument is true, the drop has been
        //successful and it's time to remove the selected items 
        //from the list. If the remove argument is false, it
        //was a Copy operation and the original list is left
        //intact.
        protected void cleanup(JComponent c, boolean remove) {
            if (remove && indices != null) {
                JList source = (JList)c;
                DefaultListModel model  = (DefaultListModel)source.getModel();
                //If we are moving items around in the same list, we
                //need to adjust the indices accordingly, since those
                //after the insertion point have moved.
                if (addCount > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
                        if (indices[i] > addIndex) {
                            indices[i] += addCount;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = indices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    model.remove(indices[i]);
                }
            }
            indices = null;
            addCount = 0;
            addIndex = -1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "remove" the data from the source once the export has been completed successfully.

In order to do this, you need to override the [`TransferHandler.exportDone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#exportDone%28javax.swing.JComponent,%20java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable,%20int%29) method.

> protected void exportDone(JComponent source,
>                 Transferable data,
>                 int action)
>
> Invoked after data has been exported. This method should remove the
>   data that was transferred if the action was MOVE.
>
> This method is implemented to do nothing since MOVE is not a supported
>   action of this implementation (getSourceActions does not include
>   MOVE).

Basically, from there you need to check the `action` type and make sure the target component has accepted the `MOVE` and not simply `COPY`'ed it and remove the element from the source list.