# Java: DropTarget: Forward Transferable to JTable inside

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, drag-and-drop

I've enabled the Drag'n'Drop facilities of a `JTable` by setting a `TransferHandler` to it. Now I can add items and reorder them inside this table. For easier adding items from another location (let's say windows desktop) I also set a `DropTarget` to the `JPanel` which holds the table and some other components. This `DropTarget` simply forwards the `Transferable` to the table's `TransferHandler` which adds the item at the end of the list:

```
panel.setDropTarget(new DropTarget(table, new DropTargetAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde){
        TransferSupport transferSupport = new TransferHandler.TransferSupport(table, dtde.getTransferable());
        table.getTransferHandler().importData(transferSupport);
    }
}));
```

I've instantiated 4 of these panels so I can both add items from outside and move them from one to another panel.

That works for me, except the fact, that it performs always a COPY, not a MOVE. If I ask the `DropTargetDropEvent` for the DropAction with `getDropAction()` an exception with "Not a Drop" is thrown. (strange: Why exists a `DropTargetDropEvent` which isn't a drop?)

An exportDone() is also implemented and works correct when I drop directly into the body of the table. When dropping on the underlaying panel, exportDone() is invoked too, but with SourceAction==NONE (int 0).

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to perform the right (COPY or MOVE) action when dropping on one of my panels?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573312/drag-and-drop-in-jlist-is-not-wokring/12574266#12574266) example

Comment: thanks 4 the link. An `exportDone()` is already implemented and works correct when I drop directly into the body of the table. When dropping on the underlaying panel, `exportDone()` is invoked too, but with `SourceAction`==NONE (int 0). I'll update my question with these infos.